# PHP: destroy $_COOKIES only but not $_SESSION?

Tags: php, session-cookies, php-5.4

I just want to destroy all $_COOKIES info but not the info/ data in $_SESSION, so I use this code below, but it destroy all my $_SESSION data as well which is not what I want,

```
// Destroy all cookies.
foreach ( $_COOKIE as $key => $value ){
    setcookie( $key, "", time()-1800, '/' );
}
```

But the $_SESSION data remains undestroyed if I unset the $_COOKIES data one by one, such as,

```
setcookie('accept_terms_conditions', "", time()-1800, '/');
```

Why does the `foreach` code destroy $_SESSION as well. Can I just destroy $_COOKIES only?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you start a session the `PHPSESSID` will be added to the `$_COOKIE` array, which you reset when setting the `setcookie` using the foreach.

You can try this:

```
// Destroy all cookies.
foreach ( $_COOKIE as $key => $value ){
    if($key != 'PHPSESSID'){
        setcookie( $key, "", time()-1800, '/' );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Session generally (it's php.ini parameter) use cookie. So you have to filter on the cookies you want to destroy to not destroy the one use by the sessions.
The cookie name is by default "PHPSESSID", but it may be something else, use session_name() to get it.

```
foreach ( $_COOKIE as $key => $value ){
    if ( $key != session_name() ) { 
        setcookie( $key, "", time()-1800, '/' );
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with your method here, but the `session_name()` is an expensive method to use. And as how the developer already has set (or not) a `session_name()` themselves before, it seems irrelevant to check on that here again.

Comment: You're right. I should have used a variable, set outside of the foreach loop to store the session_name() content only once. And using session_name() ensures you that if you (or another team colleague) change the session name, your code will keep working without any other change.

Comment: As I said, I do agree with you there :-)